# Why does this array loop?

Tags: java

I don't see why the code would not end after the first iteration. Shouldn't the loop end once i = 1? since with an array.length of 3, that is divided by 2 would be 1, and 1<1 is false. This array is code is meant to detect a palindrome, so the current code reads false, with {2, 5, 2} would read true. Thank you for your help.

```
public class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = true; 
        int[] a = {2, 5, 8};

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length/2; ++i)
            if (a[i] != a[a.length - i - 1]) {
                b = false;
                break;
            }

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't end after the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

It does end after the first iteration.

It return `false` because you wrote `8` as last value in the array..
If you change that to the value `2` it return `true`

In the first iteration you are confronting the value `2` with `8` hence the main return `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I know it ends after the first iteration, I am trying to understand why it ends, not whether or not it does

Comment: @gloob: `if (a[i] != a[a.length - i - 1])` for `i=0` is `if(a[0] != a[2])` or `if(2 != 8)` which is true of course. So it enters the if block on first iteration. Why would you expect it doesn't?

Comment: it ends because the if condition is `true` end you have a `break` in the block code. It also ends because the condition in the `forloop` is false after 1st iteration

Answer (score 0):

The code works as intended. It just runs and prints b, which in this case is "false"

Comment: that might be true, but it does not answer the question

Comment: Question: I don't see why the code would not end after the first iteration.
Answer: The code works as intended.

What is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It worked perfectly for me. Maybe you should delimitate you loop with brace.
if you don't and your indentation is not welldone you will have infinite loop.